# How can I use msbuild to download a file?

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

Is there a built in way to download a file to a local directory using HTTP?

I can shell out to wget or write a custom task, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't an existing way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) has a task WebDownload which seems to be what you require.

Answer (score 28):

In MSBuild 4.0 you can use inline tasks to avoid needing to compile and deploy a custom task in a separate assembly.

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="DownloadFile" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Address ParameterType="System.String" Required="true"/>
      <FileName ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
            new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadFile(Address, FileName);
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="DownloadSomething">
    <DownloadFile Address="http://somewebsite/remotefile" FileName="localfilepath" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: When I first read this it wasn't obvious where to put the two elements. I added <UsingTask> above the <ItemGroup> containing my project files and I put <DownloadFile> in <Target Name="AfterBuild">.

Comment: Unluckily this does not work with the dotnet core version of MSBuild.

Answer (score 15):

The DownloadFile task is available in MSBuild 15.8 and above (since August 14, 2018)

example:

```
    <PropertyGroup>  
      <LicenceUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/msbuild/master/LICENSE</LicenceUrl>
    </PropertyGroup>  

    <Target Name="DownloadContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <DownloadFile
            SourceUrl="$(LicenceUrl)"
            DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
        <Output TaskParameter="DownloadedFile" ItemName="Content" />
      </DownloadFile>
    </Target>
```

For more details: [DownloadFile task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/downloadfile-task?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Works in dotnet core 5.0.

Answer (score 12):

If you're trying to download a file that requires authentication (such as TFS Web, or an IIS server attached to a domain), neither the MSBuild Extension Pack nor the MSBuild Community Tasks seem to have the ability to give a username or password to the HTTP server. In this case, I ended up writing a custom MSBuild task. Here's what I did.

I followed the advice of Stack Overflow user Doug, in his answer for [Download a file which requires authentication using vb.net/c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764815/download-a-file-which-requires-authentication-using-vb-net-c), in which he suggests some code to add to a method written by Tom Archer on the Code Guru web site.

So I used MS Visual Studio 2010 to create a new C# project with the following code to create an MSBuild target named Wget (full source code shown):

```cs
// Include references to the following frameworks in your solution:
// - Microsoft.Build.Framework
// - Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0
// - System
// - System.Net

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace Wget
{
    public class Wget: Task
    {
        [Required]
        public String Address // HTTP address to access
        { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String LocalFilename // Local file to which the downloaded page will be saved
        { get; set; }

        public String Username // Credential for HTTP authentication
        { get; set; }

        public String Password // Credential for HTTP authentication
        { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            int read = DownloadFile(Address, LocalFilename, Username, Password);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes written", read);

            return true;
        }

        public static int DownloadFile(String remoteFilename, String localFilename, String httpUsername, String httpPassword)
        {
            // Function will return the number of bytes processed
            // to the caller. Initialize to 0 here.
            int bytesProcessed = 0;

            // Assign values to these objects here so that they can
            // be referenced in the finally block
            Stream remoteStream = null;
            Stream localStream = null;
            WebResponse response = null;

            // Use a try/catch/finally block as both the WebRequest and Stream
            // classes throw exceptions upon error
            try
            {
                // Create a request for the specified remote file name
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(remoteFilename);
                if (request != null)
                {
                    // If a username or password have been given, use them
                    if (httpUsername.Length > 0 || httpPassword.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string username = httpUsername;
                        string password = httpPassword;
                        request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
                    }

                    // Send the request to the server and retrieve the
                    // WebResponse object 
                    response = request.GetResponse();
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        // Once the WebResponse object has been retrieved,
                        // get the stream object associated with the response's data
                        remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                        // Create the local file
                        localStream = File.Create(localFilename);

                        // Allocate a 1k buffer
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead;

                        // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until
                        // no bytes are returned
                        do
                        {
                            // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                            bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            // Write the data to the local file
                            localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                            // Increment total bytes processed
                            bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the response and streams objects here 
                // to make sure they're closed even if an exception
                // is thrown at some point
                if (response != null) response.Close();
                if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
                if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
            }

            // Return total bytes processed to caller.
            return bytesProcessed;
        }
    }
}
```

With that in place, I can add the following task to my MSBuild project:

```
<!-- Get the contents of a Url-->
<Wget
    Address="http://mywebserver.com/securepage"
    LocalFilename="mydownloadedfile.html"
    Username="myusername"
    Password="mypassword">
</Wget>
```

The Wget task downloads the page served by mywebserver.com and saves it to a file in the current working directory as mydownloadedfile.html, using the username "myusername" and password "mypassword".

However, in order to use the custom Wget MSBuild task, I must tell MSBuild where to find the Wget assembly file (.dll). This is done with MSBuild's  element:

```
<!-- Import your custom MSBuild task -->
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="MyCustomMSBuildTasks\Wget\bin\Release\Wget.dll" TaskName="Wget" />
```

If you want to get fancy, you can even have your MSBuild project build Wget before it's called. To do that, build the solution with the `<MSBuild Projects>` task, and import it with the `<UsingTaks AssemblyFile>` task, something like this:

```
<!-- Build the custom MSBuild target solution-->
<MSBuild Projects="MyCustomMSBuildTasks\CustomBuildTasks.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release" />

<!-- Import your custom MSBuild task -->
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="MyCustomMSBuildTasks\Wget\bin\Release\Wget.dll" TaskName="Wget" />

<!-- Get the contents of a Url-->
<Wget
    Address="http://mywebserver.com/securepage"
    LocalFilename="mydownloadedfile.html"
    Username="myusername"
    Password="mypassword">
</Wget>
```

If you've never created a custom MSBuild target before, it's not too difficult -- once you know the basics. Look at the C# code above, take a look at the official MSDN documentation, and search around on the web for more examples. A good place to start is:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx

Comment: communitytask's WebDownload does now support authentication.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the the WebDownload task in the MSBuild Community Tasks project, the MSBuild Extension pack (current version: 4.x) has a `WebClient` class that can be used to download a file. You can download the MSBuild extension pack here:

- http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com

Here is an example of using the MSBuild Extension Pack 4 to download a file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    <TPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Common\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Common\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(TPath)"/>
<Target Name="Default">
    <!-- Download a File-->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.WebClient TaskAction="DownloadFile" Url="http://hlstiw.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p7GhsJWeF4ig_Yb-8QXeA1bL0nY_MdOGaRQ3opRZS0YVvfshMfoZYe_cb1wSzPhx4nL_yidkG8Ji9msjRcTt0ew/Team%20Build%202008%20DeskSheet%202.0.pdf?download" FileName="C:\TFS Build 2008 DeskSheet.pdf"/>
    <!-- Get the contents of a Url-->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.WebClient TaskAction="OpenRead" Url="http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com">
        <Output TaskParameter="Data" PropertyName="Out"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.WebClient>
    <Message Text="$(Out)"/>
</Target>
```

As mentioned in a different answer, `WebClient` does not appear to have the capability to download from a secure (password protected) web server.