# Steps to monitor website status with teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I'm newbie to teamcity.

I want to create some steps which checks given url and mail status on every hour.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Teamcity is not a monitoring tool, it's a build/deploy tool.

Comment: @DanHoerst You are right. But still i want to do this stuff. Am I able to do It via Ieamcity or any other suggestion to complete my objective. Please help.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom [MSBuild target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089452/how-can-i-use-msbuild-to-download-a-file) that gets a url of your choice, and process the information, mail or whatever you like in that MSBuild target.

Then you can use a [Schedule trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers), and have it fire at the interval you choose.